# Trying to fill a PHP variable with a mysql query. Then updating another table with the data from that query

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

First post, here it goes. 
So this is the code that I have so far:

```
include('Connection/connect-test.php');
$selected1 = $_POST['selected'];
$sqlget = "SELECT paymentid FROM highschoolpayment WHERE hsgameid = '$selected1'";
$sqldata = mysqli_query($dbcon, $sqlget); 
$sqlupdate = "UPDATE highschool SET paymentid = '$sqldata' WHERE hsgameid = '$selected1'";
mysqli_query($dbcon, $sqlupdate);
```

What I'm trying to do is grab the 'paymentid' from the 'highschoolpayment' table and store that value into the `$sqldata` variable (line 4). Then I want to update a value in the 'highschool' table using the value that I got from line 4 as well as a value that was pulled from a `POST` submission (line 6). I know for a fact that the first 3 lines execute as they should. It is after those lines when things become iffy. I don't see the form (reappear) like I normally would when everything else is working. To me, this indicates that the PHP has successfully run. I go to the 'highschool' table but I don't see the value (paymentid) that I am expecting to see. I personally can't think of a single reason why this wouldn't work, but, I am not that experienced in PHP or MySQL so I am open to any help that I can get.

I hope this makes sense without seeing the structure of the tables but if I need to post those, let me know. I've spent a couple hours trying to troubleshoot this problem but with no forward progress.

Thanks!

Comment: you're missing a step. `$sqldata` contains the response, you need to use [`mysqli_fetch_assoc`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) to transform it into usable data

Comment: `$sqldata` is a resource, not returned data.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Could you guys post a revision of my code?

Comment: Thanks so much for the super quick help! First response coming in seconds, yes, seconds after the posting. Correct answer has to go to asprin this go around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this query returns only one row:

```
$sqldata = mysqli_query($dbcon, $sqlget);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($sqldata);
$paymentid = $row['paymentid']; // then use $paymentid in the next query
$sqlupdate = "UPDATE highschool SET paymentid = '$paymentid' 
              WHERE hsgameid = '$selected1'";
if(mysqli_query($dbcon, $sqlupdate)){
   echo 'Update successfull';
} else {
   echo 'Update query is wrong. The query generated was <br />'.$sqlupdate;
}
```

Comment: You're onto something with this! Thanks so much! Only issue now is that the highschool table paymentid is now set to 0, regardless of the paymentid found in line 3 of your snippet. I'm gonna troubleshoot and see if I can see what is going on.

Comment: After tinkering with this one, I finally got what I wanted. I checked out a YouTube video and he had        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($sqldata, MYSQLI_ASSOC); I changed only this and presto! Everything is working!

Comment: That's good. Self-learning is the best way to learn things :)

Answer (score 0):

try like this,

```
include('Connection/connect-test.php');
$selected1 = $_POST['selected'];
$sqlupdate = "UPDATE highschool SET paymentid = (select paymentid FROM highschoolpayment WHERE hsgameid = '$selected1') where hsgameid = '$selected1'";   
mysqli_query($dbcon, $sqlupdate);
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to do fetch_assoc(), and while you are at it you should parameterize your query to make it more secure, good practice for the future. here is what your code should look like

```
$selected1 = $_POST['selected'];
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost","user","pass","database");//i connect this way to my database

//the first statement that will get your paymentid
$stmt = $connect->prepare("SELECT paymentid FROM highschoolpayment WHERE hsgameid = ?")
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 's', $selected1);//'s' is for string, 'i' for int, google rest
$stmt->execute();   
$result = $stmt->get_result();

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){//it fetches each id 

    //the second statement that will use the payment id and update the database
    $stmt2 = $connect->prepare("UPDATE highschool SET paymentid = ? WHERE hsgameid = ? ;")
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt2, 'ss',$row['paymentid'], $selected1 );//'s' is for string, 'i' for int, google rest
    $stmt2->execute();
    $stmt2->close();

}

$stmt->close();
```

I just threw this quickly together, so if anyone sees something wrong don't hesitate to edit it or mark it down if completely wrong, Would rather that.

Comment: This is very nice. I like the idea of having things more secure. Unfortunately, this leaves me at the blank page once again. I substituted 's' for 'i' since I am dealing with only integers but this didn't seem to help the case. Another question, did you mean to put a question mark in? Or was I supposed to substitute something else in for that?

Comment: I put them both there because they are the changing variables, i will have a look at the syntax again to see if I  missed anything

Comment: in the while loop i forgot to change the $stmt in bind_param to $stmt2, see if that fixes it